# The error comes as can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reverse the Jamies_list and Drews list should be in first then attach both the list and I want to return the complete list.

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  return(list2+list1.reverse())
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Comment: `.reverse()` is an inplace operation. It won't return the reversed list, it returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.reverse()` is an inplace operation. It won't return the reversed list, it returns `None`

Use `sorted(list1, reverse=True)`.

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  return(list2+sorted(list1, reverse=True))
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

ELSE

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  list1.reverse()
  return(list2+list1)
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

ELSE

```
def combine_lists(list1, list2):
  # Generate a new list containing the elements of list2
  # Followed by the elements of list1 in reverse order
  return list2 + list1[::-1]
    
Jamies_list = ["Alice", "Cindy", "Bobby", "Jan", "Peter"]
Drews_list = ["Mike", "Carol", "Greg", "Marcia"]

print(combine_lists(Jamies_list, Drews_list))
```

Comment: The output for this code is ```['Mike', 'Carol', 'Greg', 'Marcia', 'Peter', 'Jan', 'Cindy', 'Bobby', 'Alice']```  here Jamies_list is not properly reversed.

Comment: for Bobby and Cindy

Comment: Yes, it reverse the `Jamies_list` and puts `Drews_list` in the front during combination of both lists

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Here the sorted() function sorts the list in reverse order but I want to reverse the list from bottom to top

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

**reverse()** is an inbuilt method in Python programming language that **reverses objects of the list in place**

You can also check it by using print(list1.reverse()). It will print None.

So would suggest using `return list2 + list1[::-1]`